# SPSS style custom tables in Orange

Tags: clustering, orange

Is there a way to draw custom tables like in SPSS where you put some attributes to rows and some to column to visualize clustering results?

Comment: Did you mean like a _scatter plot_?

Comment: No, i meant custom tables where you can customize columns and rows according to your needs.

Comment: Sorry, you mean customize columns and rows as in add new columns/rows and the data within?

Comment: Oh, I know! Do you mean like _Select Rows_ and _Select Columns_ widgets? Or perhaps the _Feature Constructor_ widget? There's also the _Data Table_ widget and its selection is passed further down the data flow ... Is this is? :D